# digest HTTP Authentication using iPhone programming?

Tags: iphone, http, authentication, digest

I'm trying to connect to an webservice using digest HTTP Authentication through iPhone programming.Is it possible through iPhone.Please provide a link or sample code for this type of authentication.

I have been through details given by apple for the same,but i need some details like how it works for iphone.very less information is available on apple documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#handling_http_authentication) should handle what you're looking for. I'm not sure exactly what sample code would be for the digest authentication, but their [main page](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) says it's supported.

Comment: Thanks For your reply Jeremy,I have already been through the ASIHTTPRequest.It is only mentioned on main page and of no help with implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The docs actually do have a pretty good overview of how to do this. I answered the same question here:

[HTTP Authentication in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821121/http-authentication-in-iphone/5823027#5823027)