# HTTP Authentication in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, http, authentication

I am hoping someone can help me with a question i have relating to  Authentication in  Xcode
Basically i have a MS Sharepoint server which return XML.
Im Having this piece of code for authentication but it is unaccessible.

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://example.com/";

NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithString:@"username:password"];
NSData *myDate = [str1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *str2 = [Base64 encode:myDate];
NSLog(@"%@ str1 %@", str2,str1);

[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",str2] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Even I m passing correct credentials, but the server is not accepting.
It returns

**401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.**

Can any1 Help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `NSURLConnection`'s `-connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:` delegate method to detect when authentication is required. In short, you'll be using NSURLCredential instances to attach authentication to the request.

The docs have a good overview and code sample:

[Responding to an Authentication Challenge](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html)

Answer (score 7):

Consider using the open source [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) class as it makes [authenticated requests](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#handling_http_authentication) pretty simple.

Comment: I was just writing the very same answer. +1