# How to implement authentication for RSS in xcode

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, rss

I am developing an ios app in xcode 4.6 that retrieves a RSS feed from a XML, but i need to pass username and password in order to authenticate. So how do i pass the username and password from my app to authenticate to get the RSS contents?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're talking about HTTP authentication check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821121/http-authentication-in-iphone

Comment: yes actually i want to perform HTTP authentication... thanks for the link... this is really helpful i am working on it. thanks.